# TortoiseHG - Change previous commit's username?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I am pretty new to HG and when I initially set it up I didn't setup my username for my local repositories.  My commits display the current logged in user and machine name.  i.e. `adam@mypc` and after setting my username I now have `adam`.

I would like to know if it is possible to change the previous commits that say `adam@mypc` to display `adam`.

I have multiple PCs that I work from and I'd like to keep all of the commits under the same username.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the committer isn't set at push time, it's set at commit time, and it's an unchangeable part of the changeset itself.  You could re-write the changesets with new names (easiest would be using the `convert` command with an `--authormap`) but it will change hashes of those changesets and invalidate any clones out there.  Going forward you can set that value as the `username` in the `[ui]` section of your `~/.hgrc` file to make sure they're the same across all your machines.

Comment: Thanks, does it matter if it is in the .hgrc file at the repository level, or will setting it at the global level accomplish the same thing?

Comment: Wherever you set it it's in effect if it's parsed/run.  So put it in your home dir's .hgrc if you want it for all your accounts, in .hg/hgrc if you want it just for that repo, and in /etc/mercurial/hgrc if you want it system wide (likely you don't)